# html DOM only scrape largest image

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I have a bookmarklet which looks at a page and extracts all the images for the user to see.

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

function getUrlAddress()
{
/*** check for https is on or not ***/
$url = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? 'https' : 'http';
/*** return the full address ***/
return $url .'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}

/*** example usage ***/
echo getUrlAddress ();

$html = file_get_html($url);

foreach($html->find('img') as $e)
    echo '<img src='.$e->src .'><br>';
```

Now, most of the time the user will click a page with a particular product on it, maybe from ebay or amazon etc - ideally, I want to show the actual image from a product as opposed to every logo/button etc but how?

I understand they don't wrap them in tags like  so is there another way to do it?

Maybe by size? size of image in px and/or file size? (Would this be indicative anyway? it's a bit of an assumption)

Two examples so you can see what I mean, if you use the above code (you'll obv have to get simple_html_dom.php)

[Amazon example](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Duke-Nukem-Forever-Xbox-360/dp/B004JHY42K/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1327304137&sr=8-1)
[ebay example](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/DUKE-NUKEM-FOREVER-XBOX-360-MICROSOFT-GAME-BRAND-NEW-SEALED-PAL-UK-SHO19VH-/160718835855?pt=UK_PC_Video_Games_Video_Games_JS&hash=item256b96d08f)

**UPDATE**

Amazon actually does something similar I've found - it can never be perfect as you're relying on all dev people writing the same, ain't gonna happen! This is closest to the functionality I need. It doesn't only scrape largest image but it seems to only scrape images relevant to the item, clever stuff?

[Amazon wish list button](http://www.amazon.co.uk/wishlist/get-button)

Comment: [Simple HTML DOM Documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

Comment: Since you're using/trying to create a bookmarklet, have you considered writing the code in javascript? And only passing the found image to your server? I guess this will be much easier to handle, and you could even add some kind of UI to get the users approval.

Comment: @Yoshi thanks, i'm not that hot on js unfortunately...you have example code? Also, you mean approval by showing all the images then letting the user choose one? Yeah, that would be ideal, but again, I'd rather just have images relevant to the item.

Comment: I'll try to give an example. About the approval: you could sort the found images by relevance (e.g. biggest images first, no body-backgrounds, reasonable format (e.g no 1px/200px)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like eBay uses id="i_vv4-35" and Amazon has onclick="openImmersiveView(event)"

Try doing something like:

```
if($site == 'eBay' && $e->id == 'i_vv4-35');
if($site == 'Amazon' && $e->onclick == 'openImmersiveView(event)');
```

Comment: That works for ebay and amazon yes, but it needs to be generic - I just found something that does but don't know how - will update the question

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($html->find('img') as $e)
if (strpos($e,'SX300') !== false) { 
    $image = $e;
}
else if (strpos($e,'SY300') !== false) { 
    $image = $e;
}
```